# Sphere equation with higher power

Tags: terminology

The shape described by $x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = 1$ is a *sphere*.  But what do you call the shape described by $x^4 + y^4 +z^4 = 1$?  Does it have a name?

Comment: Yes, the $L^4$ unit sphere.

Comment: not one that caught on. Dirichlet came up with a method for finding the volume of such shapes, along with more complicated integrals. Has the gamma function in it, $8 \Gamma \left( \frac{5}{4} \right)^3 /  \Gamma \left( \frac{7}{4} \right)$ But not the surface area

Comment: The region satisfying $|x|^\sigma+|y|^\sigma+|z|^\sigma\leq 1$ is sometimes called a superball; see e.g. this Inventiones paper by J.A. Rush http://www.digizeitschriften.de/en/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002106957 and this one by Elkies, Odlyzko and Rush http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002108941 .

Comment: Also the quartic Fermat surface (if you're doing algebraic geometry or Diophantine equations).

Comment: Related is the notion of a [superellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) and a [superellipsoid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superellipsoid.html) (some lesser known references can be found [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6637157)).